# casting an object as a spritebatch in XNA and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xna-4.0

I have a gameComponent that needs to access a game.service.  In the following example, I'm receiving the error of implicit conversion from object to microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.  C# examples show that the object needs to be cast as a spritebatch.  Can anyone do this in vb.net?

Example:
    Dim spriteBatch As SpriteBatch = Game.Services.GetService(GetType(SpriteBatch))

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention, which object needs to be cast. I guess, it's the return value of GetService(). Then you want to do something like:

```
Dim spriteBatch As SpriteBatch = DirectCast(Game.Services.GetService(GetType(SpriteBatch)), SpriteBatch)
```

Maybe, a generic method will help you. With a generic method, there is no need to cast:

```
Function GetService(Of T)() As T
    '...
End Function
Dim spriteBatch = Game.Services.GetService(Of SpriteBatch)()
```